# Is it possible to add logcat window to WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I develop the React Native app with WebStorm, and I need to use a logcat for debugging.  Now I am using Android Studio for logcat, but maybe it is possible to add a logcat window to WebStorm?

Comment: No; you have to either run logcat in embedded terminal or set it up as external tool

Comment: Note that it's available in IDEA - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-with-logcat.html